# TypeError: errorScreen is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Show
C:/xampp/htdocs/screencast/src/views/lesson/Show.js:68
65 |       {(hasBought && !errorScreen) && (
66 |
67 |

> 68 |   <YouTube
> | ^  69 |  videoId={lesson.unique_video_id}
> 70 |
> 71 |  className={``}
> View compiled
> ▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
> getLesson
> C:/xampp/htdocs/screencast/src/views/lesson/Show.js:43
> 40 |
> 41 |
> 42 |            setHasBought(chekIfHasBought.data.data);
> 43 |            setLesson(lessonsResponses.data.data);
> | ^  44 |            setPlaylist(lessonsResponses.data.playlist);
> 45 |        } catch (e) {
> 46 |

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SsrY.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';
import { ListOfPlaylist } from '../../components/ListOfPlaylist';
import App from '../../layouts/App';

const Show = () => {

    const [lesson, setLesson] = useState([])

    const[playlist, setPlaylist] =  useState([])
    const[hasBought, setHasBought] =  useState([])

    const[errorScreen, setErrorscreen] = useState(false)
    const { episode, slug } = useParams()


    const onReady = ()=> {
        console.log("Kelas Bisa di tonton");
    }



    const onStateChange = () => {
        console.log(" kelas update");
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
   
           
       const getLesson = async () => {

        try {
            const lessonsResponses =await axios.get(`/api/playlists/${slug}/${episode}`)

        
            const chekIfHasBought= await axios.get(`api/cek-pembayaran-${lessonsResponses.data.playlist.slug}`)
    
    
            setHasBought(chekIfHasBought.data.data);
            setLesson(lessonsResponses.data.data);
            setPlaylist(lessonsResponses.data.playlist);
        } catch (e) {


            setErrorscreen(false)
        }

       }

     
       getLesson()

    }, [episode, slug])


    return (
        <App  >
   <div className="bg-drak mb-5" style={{marginTop: '- 48px'}}>

   <div className="container">

       {(hasBought && !errorScreen) && (


   <YouTube
  videoId={lesson.unique_video_id}                  
  
  className={``}               
  containerClassName={'ratio ratio-16x9'}                        
  onReady={onReady}      
  onStateChange={onStateChange}
   
/>
)}

{!hasBought && lesson.intro && !errorScreen (  


<YouTube

  videoId={lesson.unique_video_id}                  
  
  className={``}               
  containerClassName={'ratio ratio-16x9'}                        
  onReady={onReady}      
  onStateChange={onStateChange}
   
/>
)}


{errorScreen && <div> Silakan beli untuk </div>}


   </div>

   </div>


   <div className="container">

   <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">

                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-header bg-white border-bottom py-3">
                        <strong>{playlist.name}</strong>
                    </div>

                    <div className="card-body">
                 <ListOfPlaylist playlist={slug}/>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
        </App>
    )
}

export default Show
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests you are trying to call `errorScreen` as a function, despite it being a Boolean state variable.

Searching for all the occurrences of `errorScreen`, it looks like you have a typo in this line:

```js
{!hasBought && lesson.intro && !errorScreen (
```

This is calling `errorScreen` as a function, with `<YouTube>...` as an argument.  You probably meant the following:

```js
{!hasBought && lesson.intro && !errorScreen && (
```